# Data skew exists whereby the number of matching rows is very large

Tags: apex, largedatavolumes, selectivity

I am getting the following Error.
works fine in DEV org but throwing error in UAT. Please suggest me as I was unable to move forward.

**The Actual Error is**

> *The first validation error encountered was "Apex trigger OpportunityObject caused an unexpected exception, contact your
>   administrator: OpportunityObject: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by:
>   System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large object type
>   (more than 200000 rows). Consider an indexed filter or contact
>   salesforce.com about custom indexing. Even if a field is indexed a
>   filter might still not be selective when: 1. The filter value includes
>   null (for instance binding with a list that contains null) 2. Data
>   skew exists whereby the number of matching rows is very large (for
>   instance, filtering for a particular foreign key value that occurs
>   many times): Class.OpportunityValidator.ValidateOCR_OnOppStageChange:
>   line 14, column 1".*

```
public class OpportunityValidator {
     public static void ValidateOCR_OnOppStageChange(List < Opportunity > newOppsForUpdate, Map < Id, Opportunity > mapOldOpps) {

      if (Validator_cls.isOCRfirstRun()) {
       Map < String, OCRValidationRequiredRecordTypes__c > mapOCRRequiredRecordTypes = OCRValidationRequiredRecordTypes__c.getAll();
       Map < String, OCRValidationRequiredStages__c > mapOCRRequiredStages = OCRValidationRequiredStages__c.getAll();
       //Map < Id, String > mapRecordtypeIdName = new Map< Id, String> ();
       Map < Id, Opportunity > mapIdOppRecords = new Map < Id, Opportunity > ();
       for (Opportunity Op: [SELECT Id,OppLineItemsCount__c,  (SELECT Id FROM Opportunitylineitems) FROM Opportunity WHERE
         StageName IN: mapOCRRequiredStages.keySet() AND Status__c != 'Closed'
         AND
         Opportunity.recordtype.Name IN: mapOCRRequiredRecordTypes.keyset() AND
         Id NOT IN(SELECT Opportunityid FROM OpportunityContactRole) AND Id IN: newOppsForUpdate
        ]) {
        if ((mapOldOpps.get(Op.id).OppLineItemsCount__c == op.Opportunitylineitems.size() && op.opportunitylineitems.size() > 0)) {
         system.debug('----Inside If------OCR');
         mapIdOppRecords.put(op.id, op);
        }
       }
       for (opportunity Op: newOppsForUpdate) {
        system.debug('Op.recordtype: ' + Op);
        if (mapIdOppRecords.get(Op.Id) != NULL) {
         Op.addError(' Contact Role is Mandatory ');
        }
       }

      } // End of isOCRfirstRun If condition
     } // End of ValidateOCR_OnOppStageChange
    } // End of OpportunityValidator
```

Comment: Why do you have a status__c field on the opportunity? why not use StageName?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have one query, so the culprit is pretty clear:

```
SELECT Id,OppLineItemsCount__c,  (SELECT Id FROM Opportunitylineitems) 
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE StageName IN: mapOCRRequiredStages.keySet() 
     AND Status__c != 'Closed'
     AND Opportunity.recordtype.Name IN: mapOCRRequiredRecordTypes.keyset() 
     AND Id NOT IN (SELECT Opportunityid FROM OpportunityContactRole) 
     AND Id IN: newOppsForUpdate
```

The error message is telling you that this query is not being treated as selective; the platform will always terminate non-selective queries executed against objects with data volume > 200,000 records when run in trigger context (directly or indirectly). This helps preserve performance of the trigger and shorten transaction time.

You should take some time to read [Make SOQL query selective](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000325257&type=1&mode=1) from the knowledge base, as well as the articles linked from there. Selectivity can be complex to figure out and can depend as well on the content of the variables being bound in the query and the configuration of the database, such as whether specific fields are indexed or External Ids.

My theory is that since your `Id IN :newOppsForUpdate` should be selective (assuming that collection contains no nulls and is of reasonable size), it's actually the unfiltered semi-join subquery getting you in trouble:

```
AND Id NOT IN (SELECT Opportunityid FROM OpportunityContactRole)
```

Presumably there's more than 200,000 records in `OpportunityContactRole`, making this subquery non-selective.

I may be wrong; there's a lot of complexity to LDV SOQL optimization and I'm not a great expert in it.

However, I think there is a quite easy fix if my surmise is correct or close. Assuming, again, that `newOppsForUpdate` is of reasonable size (I'm presuming it comes from a trigger), run some of these filters in Apex rather than SOQL.

In particular, I would suggest you use a subquery to get the `OpportunityContactRoles` list for each queried Opportunity, in the same way that you already do with `OpportunityLineItems`. You would delete your `ID NOT IN()` clause.

You can then write Apex logic within the loop to exclude those `Opportunity` records having them, rather than using a semi-join. For example, inside the loop you might check `if (Op.OpportunityContactRoles.size() > 0) continue;` to skip those records.

I suspect that will cure the issue. I can't promise it, but it's a reasonable guess.

Comment: Hi David:
As you told i tried to execute the logic in Anonymous window it worked fine.
when I tried to create/update a single record on opportunity 
it is throwing me this error [even for one record]

Comment: @Muzeeb The error you are receiving will only take place in trigger context.

Comment: Hi @David:
Then how to modify my query in this case to avoid the error.?
any suggestions please

Comment: @Muzeeb My answer contains a specific suggestion. Did you try it?

Comment: Hi @David What is that suggestion pls tell me in simple words

Comment: I have edited my answer to try to make it clearer.

Comment: It worked for me , thank you very much David.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add few points to David's answer, I would mention some extra things

```
SELECT Id,OppLineItemsCount__c,  (SELECT Id FROM Opportunitylineitems) 
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE StageName IN: mapOCRRequiredStages.keySet() 
     AND Status__c != 'Closed'
     AND Opportunity.recordtype.Name IN: mapOCRRequiredRecordTypes.keyset() 
     AND Id NOT IN (SELECT Opportunityid FROM OpportunityContactRole) 
     AND Id IN: newOppsForUpdate
```

`!=` SOQL is very expensive, thus `Status__c != 'Closed'` is slowing things down.

Instead, create a Custom Formula Field `isStatusClosed__c` as Boolean and ask Salesforce Support to Index it for you. As its deterministic formula, they will be able to index it.

Also `Opportunity.recordtype.Name IN: mapOCRRequiredRecordTypes.keyset()` is again a join, instead in SOQL use recordTypeId

`Opportunity.recordtypeId IN: mapOCRRequiredRecordTypesId.keyset()`